# Create Table from variable name Values

Tags: excel, vba, range

I would like to create the table based on the "Header" name and it's last row of the table.

I could found the Header start address and Length of the table also using some formulas.

For Example:
FindHeaderValue as 14 i.e, $B$14
TableLength as 65, i.e, $V$65

Hence, I would like to create the Table with the range for
$B$FindHeaderValue:$V$TableLength .

Because the FindHeaderValue and TableLength will vary Excel to Excel.

Please help to figure out the solution for the same. Thank you so much in advance.
[image: Excel Sheet for reference]

```
            Sub Test()
            
            
            Dim sFindHeader As String
            Dim oRangeFindHeader As Range, FirstRange As String, LastRange As String
            Dim FindHeaderValue As Integer, FindLength As Integer, TableLength As Integer
            
            Dim Ws As Worksheet
            Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            
            Set oRangeFindHeader = Worksheets("8A52").Range("B1:V5000").Find("BBBB", lookat:=xlPart)
            sFindHeader = oRangeFindHeader.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
            FindHeaderValue = GetNumber(sFindHeader)
            FirstRange = oRangeFindHeader.Address
            MsgBox FindHeaderValue
            MsgBox FirstRange
            
            FindLength = FindHeaderValue + 2
            
            TableLength = Cells(FindLength, 13).End(xlDown).Row
            MsgBox TableLength
            
            
            Ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Ws.Range("$B$FindHeaderValue:$V$TableLength"), , xlYes).Name = "DefinitionTable"
            Ws.ListObjects("DefinitionTable").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"
            
            End Sub
            
            Public Function GetNumber(s As String) As Long
                Dim b As Boolean, i As Long, t As String
                b = False
                t = ""
                For i = 1 To Len(s)
                    If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) Then
                        b = True
                        t = t & Mid(s, i, 1)
                    Else
                        If b Then
                            GetNumber = CLng(t)
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                    End If
                Next i
            End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables don't belong inside quotes. Use `&` to concatenate them into the range address (which doesn't need `$` by the way):

```
Ws.Range("B" & FindHeaderValue & ":V" & TableLength)
```